# Enumeration of theorems

Tags: theorems

Suppose I want to write a theorem.

Using

```
\begin{theorem}
.......
\end{theorem
```

I obtain something like

> Theorem 0.0.1

But I want only

> Theorem 1

The preamble is

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany,italian,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\newcommand{\bs}[1]{{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposizione}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollario}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please post a minimal working example. We cannot see how you defined your `theorem` environment. BTW: This does not seem to have anything to do with either the `pdftex` or the `miktex` tags

Comment: Remove `[section]` from the `\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theorem numbering is defined in the line

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorema}[section]
```

By default, each theorem uses its own numbering (1,2,3...): the parameter "[section]" adds the "0.0." you are trying to avoid.

Further information can be found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems), in the "Theorem numbering" section.